# Regex finding youtubes links in <a> deleting hashtags posted before

Tags: javascript, regex, youtube

I'm currently working on a project which require to convert a youtube link to an iframe in a Post. My regex can do that.

However, before doing this, I have a few plugins that transform hashtags # in  and same with links like http://blablabla.bla

My problem here is that my regex transforms every hashtags posted before the youtube video and remove it. I think it comes from the .* at the beggining of my regex but I'm not really sure. I don't really know how to fix my it...

Here is my regex in regex101. But the hashtag link is not included in the full match, so right now i'm not sure of anything...

https://regex101.com/r/Myuyoq/3

Any help, clue or advise appreciated :)

PS : Here is my code right now if it can help understand better...

```
    const postContent = brify(hashtagify(linkify(usedPost.content || '', {
      className: 'linkified',
      defaultProtocol: 'https',
      target: {
         url: '_blank'
      }
    })))

    const re = /(<a .*(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_;-]+)?(&amp;list=[a-zA-Z0-9_;-]*)*<\/a>)/g,
    vid = '<iframe width="551" height="345" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/$2" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    const contentYoutube = postContent.replace(re, vid)
```

Comment: what do you want as result on that regex101 example?

Comment: I want the same result but without the .* after the <a
It will help me see from where comes my problem

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. i suspect you want to replace youtube links with that iframe?

Comment: I'm sorry if it was not clear... Yes I want to replace youtube links with an iframe but I also want to take all the <a></a> tag in order to remove it.

Comment: But without usage of the `.*`?

Comment: Yes, but if its not possible i'll try in another way with the help of your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` at the beginning makes your regex match the very first `<a` and then eat up everything till the final `</a>` preceded by the desired `href`. In order to fix it, change `.` to `[^<]` to exclude any other tag from match:

```
(<a [^<]*(?:http:\/\/|https:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?([a-zA-Z0-9_;-]+)<\/a>)
    ^^^^
    Use this instead of .
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Myuyoq/5

P.S.

You failed to show the error in your regex101.com example because the `a` tags where on separate line and `.` does not match newline characters. You could place the `a` tags on the same line to demonstrate what was intended:
https://regex101.com/r/Myuyoq/4